# ios arc memory release how to deal

Tags: ios, objective-c

now  my app memory  is 22.2M

when I push a ViewControl the memory is 24.3M

and then I pop the  ViewControl  the memory is 23.8M

why  the memory increase is more than decrease。 my app is base on ARC . what is the situation.please help me  ,thanks.

Comment: That totally depends on what kind of resources you are loading with the view controller. If you load images into a cache you could clear the cache upon dismissing the view controller.

Comment: Check with Instruments. Check Allocations and leaks and see where you are leaking.

Comment: What subviews you are adding to _self.view_? Are you removing them in _dealloc_ method?

Comment: Also check the custom delegate object types, blocks and check whether the dealloc method is invoked or not.

Comment: I not use xib or storyboard . I code  the interface. in my code  I use expression like : @property(strong) UIButton *btn;  @property(strong) NSArray *array . for memory relase how i deal with them

Comment: Even you should also consider the `pushedViewController` reference declaration in the parent class. i.e, If you declare the reference of `pushedViewController` as global variable and bind it as strong will not let ARC to clear the memory. Check this case once.

Answer (score 3):

In ARC,Whenever you push and pop a viewcontroller the memory will not get released immediately after the pop.ARC will take its own time to handle memory.